# How to explain mathematics to lay audience

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, online-resources

Does anyone have some good resources for explaining complicated mathematics (like group theory) to school students? How can I make a talk accessible?

Comment: For Group Theory, peruse these answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13320/cool-problems-to-impress-students-with-group-theory, for general, review this and the two book references: http://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math.html. For more details, see: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11224/group-theory-for-high-schoolers-want-the-opinion-of-other-educators

Comment: It's non trivial to reach out in this way but very rewarding. Use lots of figures and analogies instead of equations!

Comment: @DW_James:  Also, you might like to explore group theory and other math topics on: https://plus.maths.org/content/teacher-package-group-theory. The Math Educators stack exchange might also be a source of information for other math areas.

Comment: Remember , when speaking for non - professional audience , *'It is better to be understood than to be correct.'*

Comment: I guess you could do it on a topic which everyone knows like the rubix cube (e.g. for group theory)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the symmetries of a square and introduce them to the dihedral groups.
It is found very frequently in our surroundings. The logo of Mercedes-Benz, starfish, snowflakes are a few of the examples.

All this is given in the first chapter of the book Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph A Gallian which can be found here [https://www.amazon.com/Contemporary-Abstract-Algebra-Joseph-Gallian/dp/1305657969](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305657969)

You can also refer the two books namely:

- An inquiry-based approach to abstract algebra by Dana Ernst
- Visual Group Theory by Nathan Carter

The lecture videos available here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwTQdOop-nU&list=PLwV-9DG53NDxU337smpTwm6sef4x-SCLv) might also be helpful.